# How many jobs are available?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

The [main SO jobs page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) doesn't say how many jobs are available. Any way to find out?

Comment: I'm curious why you're curious about this. What use do you have for the count?

Comment: Search for the space character: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=+  :)

Comment: Twelve. Or more.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: One reason is that, if I search for example for 'qt', and get e.g. 3 jobs, I can interpret that either as "qt is unpopular" or as "the SO Job site is unpopular", and I can see which of the two is correct if I know the total number of jobs.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Comment: More accurately, "the SO job site is unpopular among shops that use Qt".

Comment: What, are you going to apply for all of them?

Comment: @CodyGray: lol "shops". _"Good morning, I would like some Qt please." "Certainly, sir."_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [QuickTrip](http://www.quiktrip.com/Jobs) (QT) ***is** always* hiring.

Answer (score 10):

You can click on the ["most recent" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab&sort=p). This will display all available jobs in your region, ordered by recency.

Comment: What do you mean by "region"? I see jobs all over Europe in the list.

Comment: @DavidG "region" = the job's targeting region. If Company A is targeting their job to Spain, users in Spain will see the job in their "most recent" results. If Company B is targeting their job to the EU (which I believe is the default practice), all users in the EU will see the job in this list.